# On line Table editor for MS SQL Server / Access?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, ms-access, database-connection

I'm searching for a on line database table editor for SQL or Access that allows editing of records. Does it exist a .net application?
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://sqlwebtools.codeplex.com/ should do what you want (for SQLServer).

> SQL Server Web Tools is a Web-based
>   Administration tool to manage SQL
>   Server databases. With SSWT, you can
>   administer accounts, manage databases
>   and tables, write and run queries and
>   Stored Procedures, and much more.

Answer (score 0):

you can try Table Smart Editor (http://www.tablesmarteditor.com/) for Access 2003/2007  and SQL Server